# Drupal 8 get data from table?

Tags: drupal-8

this is my code.

```
     $connection = Database::getConnection();
    $sth = $connection->select('node_field_word_record', 'x')
        ->fields('x', array('field_word_record_useruuid'));
    $data = $sth->execute();
    $results = $data->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    print_r($results);
```

but $_results is empty.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HqEX.png)

this is error message.

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper：Drupal\record_json\Controller\RecordJsonController->save_words() 中的 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fire.node_field_word_record' doesn't exist: SELECT x.field_word_record_useruuid AS field_word_record_useruuid FROM {node_field_word_record} x;
```

place help me guys!

Answer (score 0):

It was sheer stupidity on my part guys,the rong is `node_field_word_record`,there is missing  a `_`,the right table name is `node__field_word_record`.